# Find range and return range value to different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two data sheets, one sheet contains [lower ends of ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZzs5.png) (e.g A1, B2 C3, E7, F1, G18 and I1), the other sheet contains [information modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUwQs.png).

Now I am trying to use VBA to take the lower range value, find the upper range value in the information module sheet based on the empty cells at the end of the range, combine the two values to a range(e.g. A1:A1, B2:B2, C3:C3, E7:E11, F1:F8, G18:G26 and I1:I10) and the copy all range values down column A in third sheet:

```
HEADER1

SUBHEADER2

DEVHEADER3

FEESUB2

FEESUB2

FEESUB2

FEESUB2

FEESUB2

ABC Services1

• ABC1

• ABC2

• ABC3

• ABC4

• ABC5

• ABC6

• ABC7

CDF Services3

• ABC1 

• ABC2

• ABC3

• ABC4

• ABC5

• ABC6

• ABC7

• ABC8

Additional Services and Fees1

TEST2

TEST2

TEST2

TEST2
TEST2

TEST2

TEST2

TEST2

TEST2

TEST2

TEST2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! That's great that you are *trying to use VBA ...*. Not sure what you expect from the site, but there isn't much we can do for since you didn't 1) ask a question 2) provide any code that you have attempted. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back with a specific question.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman. Sorry, I completely lost track of my question when I was describing by task.

Comment: My question is not around a particular piece of code, but how one would tackle a problem like that. I tried to write a piece of code to determine the upper end of each range in the information modules, but already failed at that because range value is in a different sheet than the module sheet. And I spend a lot of time googling similar problems but could not find something similar.

Comment: Take it step-by-step. So you have code that you built to accomplish a particular task that is not working. Sounds like a clear and **great** question for SO. Create a question just around that issue showing us the code you've tried and exactly what *that specific function* is meant to do. Then we can help you solve it. Then you can move onto the next task and repeat if necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks Scott. Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming range starts are listed in Sheet1 A2:A8 representing the top cell in Sheet2 containing the info you want with 1 or more rows in each, then the following code will gather these lists and put them in column A of Sheet3.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetInfo()
Dim rngStart As Range
Dim rngInfo As Range
Dim Acell As Range
  Sheets(3).Activate
  For Each rngStart In Sheets(1).Range("A2:A8")
    With Sheets(2)
      Set rngInfo = .Range(rngStart.Value)
      If Not IsEmpty(rngInfo.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        Set rngInfo = Range(rngInfo, rngInfo.End(xlDown))
      End If
      For Each Acell In rngInfo
        Sheets(3).Cells(Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Formula = Acell.Value
      Next Acell
    End With
  Next rngStart
End Sub
```